# C Macro expansion failing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm pretty confused, why is this macro expansion failing to expand correctly? I’m attempting to run nested macros a number of times.

```
#define RUN1TIMES(MACRO, param) MACRO(param)
#define RUN2TIMES(MACRO, param) RUN1TIMES(MACRO, param) MACRO(param)

#define MACROA(param) param
#define MACROB(param) b = RUN1TIMES(MACROA, param)
#define MACROC(param) c = RUN2TIMES(MACROB, param)

MACROC(test);
```

Running `gcc -E`:

```
c = b = RUN1TIMES(MACROA, param) b = test;
```

Desired result (not sane C, but just to demonstrate the issue)

```
c = b = test b = test;
```

Comment: Remove parentheses from`MACROA` to move a bit farther. And note, that `RUN1TIMES` will not expand *for the second time*.

Comment: This is to avoid circular definitions: `#define A B` `#define B A`

Comment: I pass parameters in my real code, this is just simplified. Edited

Comment: Then your simplified code is not representing the real problem. Nevertheless, the root-cause is still the same. A macro cannot be expanded more than once

Comment: I’ve edited it now

Comment: what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: A macro can be replaced more than once. A macro will not be replaced again during its own replacement, but, if it appears multiple times in the replacement of another macro (not nested within its own replacement), it will be replaced each time. We see this in the code in this example, which does replace `MACROB(…)` twice in getting to the result shown in the question.

Comment: Your key problem is that both `MACROB` and `RUN2TIMES` use `RUN1TIMES`. After `RUN2TIMES` is replaced, we have `RUN1TIMES(MACROB, test)…`. This is replaced by `MACROB(test)…`, which is replaced by `RUN1TIMES(MACROA, test)`, which is not replaced because we are nested within the replacement of `RUN1TIMES`. Why do you not simply define `MACROC(param)` to be `c = MACROB(param)` and `MACROB(param)` to be `b = MACROA(param)`? What is the ultimate replacement you want to see from `MACROC(test)`?

Comment: In my real code I want to call the macro up to 10 times. I did not know that macros cannot be called recursively. One solution is just to define `RUN2TIMES(MACRO, param) MACRO(param) MACRO(param)` etc, I just thought there might be a better way.